# Limitations of StempelStemmer, Polish stemmers

Tags: nlp

I am trying to understand what is an acceptable output of a stemmer.

I have tried to stem a few words using [StempelStemmer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_1_0/analyzers-stempel/org/apache/lucene/analysis/stempel/StempelStemmer.html), an algorithmic stemmer for Polish from Apache Lucene. However, it looks it cannot handle some words properly, e.g.

> joyce -> ąć
>
> wielce -> ąć
>
> piwko -> ąć
>
> royce -> ąć
>
> pip -> ąć
>
> xyz -> xyz

1. I'm surprised it cannot handle Polish words ("wielce", "piwko" and "pip"). Is this a limitation of (a) the stemming algorithm or (b) the training dataset the algorithm used or (3) something else?
2. I am surprised that for non-Polish words it returns "ać". I would
   expect that for words it has not be trained for it will return their
   original forms, as it happens, for instance, when stemming words like
   "xyz". I understand that compared to lemmatizers, stemmers are more crude: they can cut too much. But it looks like instead of cutting it introduces completely different word. Is it a bug?